# Using Microsoft Surface controls in Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, pixelsense

This seems like it should be a simple thing, but I can't work it out; how do I get Microsoft Surface controls into Expression Blend so I can retemplate them? I have the surface SDK DLLs as references in a new Expression Blend WPF project, but the controls are not available in the 'Assets' dialog, nor can they be added to the XAML directly...

Cheers,
rJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another look this morning, and I realised my problem is likely that I am using Surface 2.0 controls - built with .NET 4.0 - and trying to load them into Expression Blend 3, which seems to be on .NET 3.5. I guess that's my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Surface, but from what I've read they should just show up.  They might not be readily apparent in the Assets tab, but if you click on Controls and then use the search functionality, you should be able to pull them up.